# How can I make Leiningen run a hook before testing?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I would like to run a function prior to CLI-initiated test runs, so that:

```
$ lein test
```

...will, for instance, configure logging to suppress messages of severity < WARN.

What is the best way to do this? Using a hook? If so, how do I restrict hook execution to 'test' only? Would I have to look up the current task during hook execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it could (depending on what's used for logging) be done in test fixtures which most testing frameworks offer, e.g. in `clojure.test`:

```
(clojure.test/use-fixtures
  :once
  (fn [f]
    (let [l (get-level)]
      (set-level! :warn)
      (try
        (f)
        (finally
          (set-level! l))))))
```

`f` is the function containing your complete test run which is called here inbetween (pseudocode!) changes to the log level.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best approach. The leiningen test task is oriented towards locating tests by scanning for namespaces, and selecting subsets of tests based on metadata.